# SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, tableview

I want to create an ***iPhone*** app that uses a navigation scene similar to the one pictured in the link

[image: screenshot]

Please note I do not want this to only work for iPad, I want it to work for iPhone exactly as pictured, when you click on a tableview item it hides the tableview and makes that view full screen. I want ideas on how to do this because I cannot figure it out myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Facebook guys have done brilliant job in the new version of the app. The similar open source code can be found from here - [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo).  Please note that as of June 2014, this project has been discontinued, so you'll probably have better luck with a project from the list below.

It reveals technique behind doing split view for iPhone.

Some other open source code:

1. [JWSlideMenu](https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu)
2. [DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController)
3. [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/)
4. [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
5. [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)
6. [MWFSlideNavigationViewController](https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController)
7. [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)
8. [SASlideMenu](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu)
9. [HHTabListController](https://github.com/gloubibou/HHTabListController)
10. [MTSlideViewController](https://github.com/myell0w/MTSlideViewController)
11. [MTStackViewController](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/MTStackViewController)
12. [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)
13. [DMSideMenuController](https://github.com/fumoboy007/DMSideMenuController)
14. [JVFloatingDrawer](https://github.com/JVillella/JVFloatingDrawer)

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, thanks, I haven't had a chance to try it out yet but it doesn't contain anything that Apple wouldn't approve, like unofficial API's or anything, does it?

Comment: Any idea how to do this on Android?

Comment: @Daniel: Nope. But you may create a new question on SO and I am sure you will get a solution.

Comment: @Sagar I already did that and doesn't seem to be working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365638/ios-facebook-slide-menu-for-android

Comment: https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu works fine. Has anyone customized any of these solutions to display a tableview with filters instead of navigation with the FB splitview controller.

Comment: @Daniel have a look to https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu for Android implementation. It's way more efficient than all other alternative..

Comment: You could add to this list UISplitViewController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/ Since iOS8 you can accomplish the split view like Facebook app in iPhone. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123004/slide-sidebar-menu-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 15):

How about projects with storyboard compatibility?
I found 1 more slide menu which is compatible with storyboards:
[SASlideMenu](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu)

Another storyboard-compatible menu is 
[ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) 
and 
[ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
from Sagar's answer. They both have storyboard examples (for the last one link is [ViewDeckStoryboardExample](https://github.com/simonrice/ViewDeckStoryboardExample))

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else looking for an Android version, take a look at:

- [android fb like slideout navigation](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation)
- [emerging ui pattern side navigation](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html)

Answer (score 3):

I realize you asked about facebook, but now that ios7 is out, and this is the defacto thread i thought id post here.

For an effect similar to the kindle app on ios7 you can use:

https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is looking for a way to implement this in `MonoTouch` now known as `Xamarin.ios`, take a look at this article I just found. [monotouch slide out navigation](http://www.dillonbuchanan.com/programming/monotouch-slide-out-navigation/)

**EDIT**

I just found that they have a free component for this!
[flyoutnavigation](http://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation/)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed no one listed this wonderful class... [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

I use it with my project apps all the time. It's Easy to use and heavily documented... There are also a few examples John gives to the user to understand how it works or if you'd like to derive your project from... Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[SHSidebarController](https://github.com/izqui/SHSidebarController)with filder effect.
This might be helpful to you.. try this :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the best match for me.

> **PKRevealController**

It has nice scroll effect with finger and moves back on partial drag.

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

Answer (score 0):

MMDrawerController is very good option.
You can configure many things. try it once
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a floating-style navigation drawer that I hope people will like. It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/JVillella/JVFloatingDrawer), take a look.

[image]