# What UIViewController do the Gmail and Facebook apps use on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Both the Gmail and Facebook apps on the iPhone use a controller I need for my app. They have a button in the upper left bar of the main screen that when pressed, a left panel slides in with a list of items. It kind of looks like a UISplitViewController on the iPad but the root panel slides in and out.

Is this a custom view controller?

Comment: Follow this link, maybe this will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355573/iphone-dev-creating-sliding-drawers-like-path-and-facebook-apps

Answer (score 2):

Facebook uses the [Three20](http://three20.info/) API for their special GUI views.

They have an overview on their website where you can see all the views it provides and find what the one you are looking for is called.

**EDIT:** But [this](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController) is what you are looking for. [More info](http://kenyarmosh.com/blog/ios-pattern-slide-out-navigation/)

**EDIT2:** Just found [this](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jwslidemenu) one too.

Comment: That control is actually a subclass of UINavigationController which Apple disallows. I've heard that they can reject your app for that.

Comment: The docs only say [This class is not intended for subclassing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). They do not say you cannot subclass `UINavigationController` and I doubt they would reject your app because of it. If you have heard of someone who has then likelihood is they ignored the advice of `don't subclass` and probably made a hash of it causing a failing app.

Comment: @Dimme Facebook built their own.

Comment: @Paul.s You may very well be right, I just remember reading a thread talking about that a while back.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a standard control for iOS however there is a perfectly good class you can download and integrate here: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddmenucontroller

Comment: So I downloaded and added the DDMenuControllers to my project, however, there are alot of compile errors. My target is iPad, iOS SDK 4.3. Is there something wrong with the source?

Comment: Could be but whenever I run into errors with an external library I usually assume it's my fault and not the library