# iPhone app with a 'Left' nav.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been asked to create an iphone app with a left nav/menu. Since there are no native UI components to use for this, I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this. The only app that I remember that had this kind of thing was the Facebook app from about 18months ago.

Is there a good 3rd party API to handle this kind of thing?

Description of the left nav: There is a permanent left nav along the left of the screen running the full length of the screen. When the user selects a menu option a UIView/UIViewController slide in from the right side and covers over the menu. A little button is left stuck to the left side of the screen. If the user selects this button the view slides back to the right again, and the leftnav menu appears from underneath the view and it is possible to interact with again.

Comment: Take a look at the answers posted on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355573/iphone-dev-creating-sliding-drawers-like-path-and-facebook-apps

Comment: This is a "Master-Detail" pattern. You might be able to find more descriptive solutions looking for that. If you are making an app for iPad, there is a native UI, I believe it's called UISplitViewController

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the problem? just create a UIView with subview containing UIButtons, you have to layout the buttons yourself (calculate the frame). Later you add that leftmenuView to the UiViewCobtroller.

Comment: There is no problem Alex, just that I do not want to reinvent the wheel, and definitely don't want to invent a poorer version of that wheel, hence why I'm looking for the opinions of others that have been down this path already.