# iOS Facebook Slide Menu for Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, uisplitviewcontroller, android-side-navigation

I am looking to create the feature described in this post [SplitView on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-but-on-iphone), but I would like it for Android. Is there any library that would help me achieve this? Would I just use fragments and if so, what would this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed just a few days after you placed your question, here on stackoverflow. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453320/android-sidebar-like-facebook-or-firefox) question for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A sample code is here [android-sliding-menu-demo](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo) which is found from one of the links mentioned in the answer from cosmix. I know it's the answer copied from another stack overflow thread only, but I still mentioned here so that users coming to this question got the direct link to the source code.