# How to cleanly superpose ScrollableViews in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-side-navigation

In order to implement a navigation bar ala [Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android) I have the following *layout* configuration:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
   <!-- This is the Lower Layer hosting the navbar -->
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
      <!-- ListView representing the navbar -->
      <ListView 
       />
   </LinearLayout>

   <!-- This is the Top Layer hosting the Content -->
   <FrameLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
   > 
      <!-- This is where the View of the Content will be injected -->
   </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So the basic idea is that when I want to open the *navbar* I just shift the *TopLayer* to the right and the navbar will be revealed.
Now this works well and I can interact with the *navbar's* `ListView` in order to navigate through the application, as far as the view that gets injected inside the `TopLayer`isn't a `ScrollableView`(like another `ListView`, a `ScrollView`or a `WebView`).

For instance, when the `TopLayer`is a `WebView`instance, I can't scroll and interact with the *navbar's* `ListView`because it is the `WebView`that gets scrolled (althoough I shifted it to the right).

I guess it's not trivial to superpose many `ScrollableView`'s but I hope there are hacks to overcome these issues.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

By the way, this is how I am shifting the `TopLayer`view (using [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)):

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0F, mListView.getWidth(), 0.0F, 0.0F);
translateAnim.setDuration(..);
translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
mTopLayerView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not due to superposing `ScrollableView`s or anything but to the fact that when using [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) the logical position (ie: not visual) of the animated view is still bound to its original position. Thus when I thought I was clicking on the navigation's item, I was in fact interacting with the `ContentView` that I thought has moved.

Now I am using [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#setPropertyName%28java.lang.String%29) which fixes this issue and it works very well. I only have to assure the compatibility with Pre-Honeycomb devices (I am thinking of using [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) for this matter. If someones knows any other alternative to fix this properly using the old animation API, feel free to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513289/android-how-to-interact-with-a-view-after-it-has-been-animated)).

Answer (score 1):

According to my app - Android UI Patterns (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns), there are 2 sample implementations of Facebook navigation and animation, this is:

- android-sliding-menu-demo: https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo
- gui-sliding-sidebar: https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar

Can you take a try if it works.