# How implement SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, android-side-navigation

I'd like to try to construct main.xml like in this application. Actually, I want construct it so that to have the same menu (with other styles).

This menu is very useful. I can pull (or drag, don't know) screen to right, and menu will be on the left side. Visual it's located on the background side.

[VK http://vk.com/doc16200012_87954624?hash=f5ac3dff8816dbd63e](http://vk.com/doc16200012_87954624?hash=f5ac3dff8816dbd63e)
[VK http://vk.com/doc16200012_87957448?hash=7b66a484606b806f29](http://vk.com/doc16200012_87957448?hash=7b66a484606b806f29)

This menu is scrollable.
[VK http://vk.com/doc16200012_87954750?hash=b1ac2c96c6fc49d532](http://vk.com/doc16200012_87954750?hash=b1ac2c96c6fc49d532)
So, how should I construct my main.xml to obtain something like this (with this menu)?

Comment: While your attempt at screenshots is admirable, it is unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: @CommonsWare application: VKontakte (you can try it, if you need it). I want to try to create menu like this (on the left side)..

Comment: @anony_root you are probably not going to get many answers if you request for people to download an application in order to help you with your question.  It could be advantageous to rework your question/screenshots so that it would not require an application download in order to answer your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated screenshots & question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [android-fb-like-slideout-navigation](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation) project on github by [Alex Korovyansky](https://github.com/korovyansk) features the type of menu you are looking for. Here is a [video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqu7YdNMzeQ&feature=youtu.be) of the functionality. The menu type is sometimes referred to as "Facebook style slide-in menu" or similar, after FB implemented it on their mobile apps.

This question has been answered several times on SO. You can find links to more implementations in these answers:

- [android-facebook-style slide.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)
- [how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android)

Comment: One difference: I have to press button to open this menu, but in this app you can pull your screen to have access to the menu.

Comment: If that's what you want to implement, you'd have to listen for the user's swipe action instead of button click.