# How to make evernote-like menu on mono for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

How to make menu like in Evernote app using Mono for Android.

[image]

Comment: What part of the menu is in question?

Comment: I want to know how to make sliding out menu, you can see it on the picture above.

Comment: What part of the picture is the menu? I just see an action bar and some content.

Comment: I think he means like the facebook app menu. If I remember correctly, someone somewhere created a similar one for android... Not sure where. A google search for facebook menu for android may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the slide in-out menu that facebook has, then this may help:

[How to make Facebook's app new menu on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but I need monodroid implementation of this menu.

Comment: How about making that implementation yourself and port the code from that project?