# Shift the screen to right on click of menu; like facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-side-navigation

In my application, I want to have behavior like facebook app wherein on click of icon I'd like to shift the whole screen towards right and display some menus on the left as shown below:

Before Clicking Menu Button

[image: Before Clicking Menu]

After Clicking Menu Button

[image: After Clicking Menu Button]

One way is to have a layout with those menu in black color and set its visibility to `gone`

But in that case, the shifting animation won't be there like it is there in facebook. So is there any way we can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Facebook's app new menu on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android facebook style slide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

Comment: here is my implementation of sliding menu http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This UI Pattern is currently being referred to as Side Navigation and discussed in some detail here:

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

The article also links to several projects that have implemented this navigation:

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

https://bitbucket.org/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu/overview

https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation

It is worth reading the article for its discussion about the issues with this kind of navigation also, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented it but give you an exact idea that you have to use fragment for this.
Go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Thanks but I think the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428416/how-to-make-facebooks-app-new-menu-on-android

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I've found https://github.com/DWorkS/ActionBarToggle because it's implementation is similar to DrawerLayout from google using ActionBarToggle. Although, it has a problem with open method but I wrote to its owner and he said that he will solve.