# Android - How to make slide menu like facebook, spotify and Google +

Tags: android

I want to add a slide menu to my app like the facebook app. I read alot of things on the internet about librarys but none worked for me. 
What is the best thing/library that i can use for this and can someone maybe explain me how to use it?

**Edit**
This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/zwemfest" >"



<com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:text="Button" />

</com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But i don't see any button or background image. Do you know whats going wrong?

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/sliding_menu_navigation_drawer/

Answer (score 20):

Well currently I'm working on a project and came across Sliding menu,i googled but get disappointed to see that no one has given some instructions or hints on how to start making a sliding menu, Every one has given link to some Github's projects/libraries to use, Hence I decided to do it myself and finally i have my own Sliding Menu Ready...

I have Spent two days on it

**1. on making animations of sliding**

**2. on making it work with all screen resolutions**

Its really easy and simple once you get some idea about **Animations**, I have read some where, its not sensible to re-invent the **Wheel**(people who are refering to github source code of sliding menu),but i believe that you should at least once try to make your own so you get a idea how it actually works and function :P

So this is a picture of how my sliding menu will going to work

**1.Find.xml** `//later in the code it will be refer as findLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/find_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/filter_button" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Islamabad"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/city">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/interested_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Men and Women"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interested_in"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="18-24 years"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/separator_1" 
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/age"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text=">30km"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/users_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:numColumns="4">

    </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include 
        layout="@layout/filter"/> //here i included the filter.xml, which is on top of find.xml layout and is initially invisible

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**2.Filter.xml** `//later in code refer as FilterLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_bg" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:background="@drawable/light_blue_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Raja Babar"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Male"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/seperator"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seperator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="22 years"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_options" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/filter_options"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/interested_in_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_options"
        android:background="@drawable/interested_in_field">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/gender"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/women_men"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/age_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interested_in_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/age_field_1">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/age"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="18-24 years"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/distance_field">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/distance"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=">30km"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd"/>


    </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

In **find.xml** i have included **filter.xml** initially which is invisible

Now **FilterAnimation.java**

```
package matchat.helpers;

import com.s3.matchat.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class FilterAnimation implements AnimationListener 
{
    Context context;

    RelativeLayout filterLayout, otherLayout;

    private Animation filterSlideIn, filterSlideOut, otherSlideIn, otherSlideOut;

    private static int otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight;

    private boolean isOtherSlideOut = false;

    private int deviceWidth;

    private int margin;

    public FilterAnimation(Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // as my animation is x-axis related so i gets the device width and will use that width,so that this sliding menu will work fine in all screen resolutions
    }

    public void initializeFilterAnimations(RelativeLayout filterLayout)
    {
        this.filterLayout = filterLayout;

        filterSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_in);

        filterSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_out);    

    }

    public void initializeOtherAnimations(RelativeLayout otherLayout)
    {       
        this.otherLayout = otherLayout;

        otherLayoutWidth = otherLayout.getWidth();

        otherLayoutHeight = otherLayout.getHeight();


        otherSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_in);
        otherSlideIn.setAnimationListener(this);

        otherSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_out);
        otherSlideOut.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public void toggleSliding()
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //check if findLayout is already slided out so get so animate it back to initial position
        {

            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideIn);

        }
        else //slide findLayout Out and filterLayout In
        {
            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideIn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //Now here we will actually move our view to the new position,because animations just move the pixels not the view
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = false;
        }
        else
        {   
            margin = (deviceWidth * 80) / 100; //here im coverting device percentage width into pixels, in my other_slide_in.xml or other_slide_out.xml you can see that i have set the android:toXDelta="80%",so it means the layout will move to 80% of the device screen,to work across all screens i have converted percentage width into pixels and then used it



            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            params.leftMargin = margin;

            params.rightMargin = -margin; //same margin from right side (negavite) so that our layout won't get shrink


            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = true;

            dimOtherLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
    {

    }

    private void dimOtherLayout()
    {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);

        alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        otherLayout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    }

}
```

**Now Find.java**

```
package main.matchat.activities;

import matchat.helpers.FilterAnimation;
import com.s3.matchat.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Find extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    RelativeLayout filterLayout, findLayout;

    Button btFilter;

    FilterAnimation filterAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find);

        filterLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.filter_layout);

        findLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.find_layout);

        btFilter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.filter);
        btFilter.setOnClickListener(this);

        filterAnimation = new FilterAnimation(this);

        initializeAnimations(); 
    }

    private void initializeAnimations()
    {   //Setting GlobolLayoutListener,when layout is completely set this function will get called and we can have our layout onbject with correct width & height,else if you simply try to get width/height of your layout in onCreate it will return 0

        final ViewTreeObserver filterObserver = filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

        filterObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

                int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                int filterLayoutWidth = (deviceWidth * 80) / 100; //here im coverting device percentage width into pixels, in my other_slide_in.xml or other_slide_out.xml you can see that i have set the android:toXDelta="80%",so it means the layout will move to 80% of the device screen,to work across all screens i have converted percentage width into pixels and then used it

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(filterLayoutWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                filterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);//here im setting the layout params for my filter.xml because its has width 260 dp,so work it across all screen i first make layout adjustments so that it work across all screens resolution 

                filterAnimation.initializeFilterAnimations(filterLayout);

            }
        });

        final ViewTreeObserver findObserver = findLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

        findObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                findLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                filterAnimation.initializeOtherAnimations(findLayout);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {

        case R.id.filter:

            filterAnimation.toggleSliding();

            break;
        }
    } 

}
```

Here are the animations res/anim

**1.filter_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true" />

</set>
```

**2.filter_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

**3.other_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-80%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true"/>

</set>
```

**4.other_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="80%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true"/>

</set>
```

There you go a complete working and functional Sliding Menu, and you can customized it to meet your requirements,if any one still have some problems setting up,feel free to ask,i feel pleasure to help you out **:)**

Comment: @GautamVasoya Yeah surely you can customize it and on Gesture event you can simply animate it

Answer (score 14):

https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation

I have been using this library these days and it works pretty well. Indeed, its usage is very straightforward.

You just declare a side_navigation.xml under your menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_chart"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_kitsch_gray"
        android:title="@string/navigation_chart"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:title="@string/navigation_info"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/navigation_photos"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_signin"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_login"
        android:title="@string/navigation_signin"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:title="@string/navigation_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Then, in your activity layout, you add the navigation View:

```
<com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And, in your activity, you link both of them:

```
SideNavigationView sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.side_navigation);
```

**EDIT:**

To trigger the side navigation panel, is a good option to call it when the user presses the home icon in the ActionBar. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, really thank you, this is so easy and so useful. But i have a problem. See my edit.

Comment: You have to remove that button off. The side navigation view will provide you everything you need to trigger it. See my edit.

Comment: @Chinaski: Hi, I am a rookie in Android development. Can you please help me with importing this library with my current project. I have downloaded a zip file from github but I don't see any .jar file. I have previously imported .jar libraries into project. But this one looks different. Help me out!!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [www.scringo.com](http://www.scringo.com). It's an SDK that allows you to add this kind of side menu with practically just this piece of code:

```
Scringo scringo = new Scringo();
scringo.init();
```

There's a lot of configuration you can do later on from the site (menu direction, colors, etc...) and can also add built-in features to the menu such as inbox, find/invite friends, radar, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Use the official version. Google released the Navigation Drawer pattern at I/O 2013 and has updated the version 4 support library to include this. :)

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 2):

You can read this 3 articles about it :

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=701

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=717

to get an idea :)

[Navigation Drawer (Google+ vs. YouTube)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-facebook)

Comment: you can also read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-facebook

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple sliding menu developed by me, check the project in github, very simple to implement
http://github.com/leonardosalles/shipp-sliding-menu

Answer (score 1):

**Slide menu** TECHNICAL IMPLEMENTATION

The side navigation is included in the Android SDK now. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

A quick search in github does reveal one project that has implemented the UI pattern.

android-fb-like-slideout-navigation at github
There's also a video demonstrating the library at work.

EDIT: Here's another library project:
https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu
Thanks Mr BuBBLs in comments!

More library project:

- https://bitbucket.org/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu/overview
- https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation
- http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/

[Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/) has also written about implementing this pattern in his blog. These posts are very much worth reading:

1. [The making of Prixing #1: Fly-in app menu](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/22/the-making-of-prixing-fly-in-app-menu-part-1/)
2. [The making of Prixing #2: Swiping the fly-in app menu](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/29/the-making-of-prixing-2-swiping-the-fly-in-app-menu/)
3. [The making of Prixing #3: Polishing the sliding app menu](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/06/08/the-making-of-prixing-3-polishing-the-sliding-app-menu/)

See also the Prixing app on the Google Play to try out the side navigation implemented by Cyril.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own Sliding menu instead of using other libraries, for better understand on how things work, then read my articles here

[Make your own sliding menu on Android tutorial – Part 1](http://www.fantageek.com/549/make-your-own-sliding-menu-on-android-tutorial-part-1/)

[Make your own sliding menu on Android tutorial – Part 2](http://www.fantageek.com/562/make-your-own-sliding-menu-on-android-tutorial-part-2/)

[image]

To achieve sliding effect, you can move the menu, or the content view, or both, all depend on your desire.

Te idea is to rely on 2 methods [offsetLeftAndRight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#offsetLeftAndRight%28int%29) and [layout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to update the view position. You 'll also need [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) to facilitate animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Two relative layouts in the xml.

```
CONTENT(initially gone)

HEADER
```

Header initially occupies all the width and content is to the left of header but is currently set to Visibility=GONE.

So when click happens on the header or any button on the header layout

Just set the width of your content layout to screen_width/2  (fraction will depend on your requirement).

```
public void onCreate(){
    RelativeLayout header=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.header);
    RelativeLayout content=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated 
    int height = display.getHeight(); // deprecated

    //on some event

    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //margin(left,right,bottom,top)
    content.setMargin(width/3,0,0,0);

    //if already opened,close the door
    content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you want some good opening animations jus use translate animation on the layouts.
And make sure to make a lyout having two relative lYouts side by side with initial configuration as mentioned at the top of my answer.