# Change direction of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left, android-menu

I am using ActionBar in my project. I want to change direction of ActionBar items means locate tab icons and logo in the right side of screen and locate menu items in the left side of screen. I googled but I didn't find any useful thing, aslo I read xml resource of theme and style in API 14 but again I didn't find any solution.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not supported.

Comment: Means it is impossible? Even I want customize ActionBar Class?

Comment: You are welcome to create your own action bar implementation, possibly forking an existing one, that does what you want. Personally, I would recommend that you leave it alone. Your users will be used to standard action bars, with elements in their standard locations. Your app will be different, and IMHO it is not likely that your users will think that yours is substantially better. You need to decide for yourself if confusing your users is worth whatever benefit you think you are gaining from this change.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think it's now supported with the new API 17 [RTL Layout Support](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)

Comment: @AhmadTK: Perhaps. It depends on what the OP is interested in achieving. RTL layout support will only reverse the direction *when the locale is set to an RTL language*. AFAIK, you cannot use the RTL layout support to reverse directions for all languages.

Comment: I think you want something like the menu implemented in Facebook, Google+ and YouTube APKs. If is that so then theres some interesting answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465774/android-how-to-make-slide-menu-like-facebook-spotify-and-google

Answer (score 5):

Action Bar now support right to left direction. It's introduced in the new API level 17 by 
adding

> android:supportsRtl attribute to the  element in your
>   manifest file and set it “true"

have a look here for more information about managing the layouts from right to left [RTL Layout Support](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)