# How to do sliding menu from right to left like Facebook,path app

Tags: android

I reffered some sliding demo in stackoverflow but still no body guiding me for right to left sliding demo.pls help me out how can i get this in android

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb

Comment: which sliding menu library are you using? so that we can tell you which class to modify to change the behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: i want exactly demo pjct for move from right to left

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564 i have created a sliding menu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook style slide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

Answer (score 1):

An Android library that allows developers to easily create slide-in menus like in the Spotify and Facebook applications. Feel free to use it all you want in your Android apps provided that you cite this project and include the license in your app.

Check this: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu