# Android sliding menu similar to the one on facebook

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm looking for a sliding menu like the one in facebook app, that is on click of left menu button the main screen slides to the right and then on click of "See all" on the slide view screen a new view slides from right to left.

Comment: Checkout below links... hope you will find what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465774/android-how-to-make-slide-menu-like-facebook-spotify-and-google

Answer (score 4):

Use Android V4 library to use "Navigation Drawer".

[Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

[Creating Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

If you want to Action Bar in Android 2.2 onwards, you can use [AppCompat Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of Google+ sliding menu using Navigation Drawer

[Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Facebook don't use the standard android APIs to creare the library. It is recommended you use the Android Navigation Drawer which provides the same sort of functionality but follows the Android guidelines.

Help on the navigation drawer can be found at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Also, if I may plug my own free open source library, I have a projecton GitHub which allows you to use the navigation drawer with multiple GUI components for easy use. The project can be found at https://github.com/BoardiesITSolutions/NavigationDrawerManager

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) which is supported by Google and follows their design guidelines.