# what are the steps to implement the slide menu in android or there are any codes

Tags: java, android, facebook, slider, mfslidemenu

I need to create an application with unknown activities. this application is the slide menu . 
i want to implement a simple slide menu as the one in the iphone(facebook) ,,but i wanna to do this in android ,, someones tells me to use the including layout in my application and in this object i have zero information and i find some complicated codes which confused me 
 any one can help me a sample ?? all i need is a sample example to under stand the idea of sliding menu , please any help 
if there isn't any piece of code i hope to tell me the steps to implement it please i want a help 
What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: Navigation drawer [**Introduction**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) and [**Implementation**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: May this [question][1] could help you to solve your problem

Cheers


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465774/android-how-to-make-slide-menu-like-facebook-spotify-and-google

Comment: @jlordo Thanks for that info seems to be better than what I have suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the layout file of your activity use Relative layout as root layout.
- At the bottom of the layout file before closing the root write the View/layoutof your slide menu. Writing at bottom keeps the menu on top of other views.
- Keep the visiblity of the slide menu layout GONE so that its initially not visible
- On click of a button on screen animate the slide menu into screen making it visible in onStart() of the animation that brings it in (You can use translate animation for this)