# Two activity animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Suppose I have activity A and B and  from activity A on click of a button we can go to activity B . But what I want is that after clicking the button, 20%(right side) of activity A is still visible on screen and 100% of activity B is visible so that total screen is divided into 20% for activity A and 80% for activity B.When I click anywhere on 20% of visible A activity, I should be able to go to activity A. How can I achieve this in android .

Comment: You may want to **look** at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadBabar the above question solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Activity is full screen. What you need is an activity with 2 fragments.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you need something like sliding menu.

I would suggest you take a look into this lib project
[android-sliding-layer-lib](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib)

here is a demo of what this project does:
[DEMO APP LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidinglayersample)