# android sliding menu library not able to extend menu width dynamically

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Currently I have used SlidingMenu Library for our project.. I stuck with some issue.. i'm not able to extend the BehindMenu width dynamically.
i.e. onClick of one of secondary menu item, width should expand from 320dp to 640dp. Please help me.

Regards
vijay

Comment: Show some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564 the slider width will adjust dynamically according to screen resolution