# Fragment side by side android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry, my English is not good. How can I show fragments side by side so that when the user clicks a button in fragment A, fragment B is shown (80%)?

[image]

Comment: here is a example of sliding menu, you can implement fragments by yourself http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the below links. It may help you

https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to put a side menu in there that can be moved in and out you could try the Navigation Drawer by Google and it should do the job. Read about it here: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: do you even use this?

Comment: @AfonsoMatlhombeJunior Yes I do and it works very well for what I need it to do, So a simple menu bar down the side of the screen that can be moved in and out when the user wants to.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to increase you answer level, it was very useful i got it(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to display a fragment on a button click.
You can simply use replace function to replace the fragment on button click like this:

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.replace("layoutName",fragmentB)

Comment: With your code it will replace all 100% fragmentA, i want fragmentA(20%) and fragmentB(80%).