# Android left to right slide drawer

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

Hi I am working with android.I need to create a slider drawer in my app.I had searched a lot for to create a left to right slide drawer as in the image.I want a smooth transition on swiping the handle button.How Can I create a left to right sliding drawer.Thanks in advance :)[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564

Comment: Also now NavigationDrawer is added in android design pattern https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: how can I change button position as in the picture in navigation drawer ?

Comment: Button is simple a child inside the layout you can put it anywhere in your layout.

Comment: Go through this link. http://sampleprogramz.com/android/slidingdrawer.php

Comment: I already used tha code but no such smooth transition here that i want

Comment: As u said How can I used navigation drawer with home button(handler)in my custom position ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to make slide menu like facebook, spotify and Google +](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465774/android-how-to-make-slide-menu-like-facebook-spotify-and-google)

Comment: Home button is a `View` inside your `layout` you can place it any where for example in your case `button` should have attribute `android:centerVertical = true` assuming `RelativeLayout` as parent.