# How to show two layout together in activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu, android-sliding, jfeinstein

Split page in Android, I need to slide the second page on top of another.

Layout 1 covering 80% of the page to the left.
Layout 2 showing on the rest of the 20%. to the right.

Then I need to drag/slide layout 2 on top of layout 1 and the slide it back.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), but I don't know how to configure this for my requirement?

What I Really need is shown in below as screenshots

**OnLoad**

[image]

**After Slide**

[image]

**Slide Back**

[image]

Comment: You can customize this if you read the whole answer carefully.http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879886/1939564

Comment: You can use native `NavigationDrawer` to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [SlidingPaneLayout](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/exploring-slidingpanelayout/), like google Hangouts app. It works what you want. Documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

Comment: I have updated the question with my requirement screenshots. Please take a look at it and help me achieve it. I am new to android.

Comment: If you're new, it's an opportunity to learn. Read the Documentation

Comment: @SQLiteNoob I had read all the documentation, I am able to scroll the views. but not able to get what i need. please check the screenshots. What i need on Onload on what i need on scroll and what i need after scroll back

Answer (score 1):

You can like this. try

```
<FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#D6FFD6"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <ImageView
                     android:src="@drawable/android"
                     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
         <TextView
                      android:text="learnandroideasily.blogspot.com"
                      android:textSize="30sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textColor="#003399"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also you can follow 3 tutorial site. where easily explain frame layout of android. such as

number #1 [Frame Layout In Android](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/frame-layout-in-androis.html)

number #2 [Android User Interface Design: Frame Layouts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-frame-layouts--mobile-4877)

and finally number #3 [Android Frame Layout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

Comment: I have updated the question with my requirement screenshots. Please take a look at it and help me achieve it. I am new to android.

Comment: @Kablu Could you please check this?

Comment: @kablu , I tried all the above, but couldnt get what i need.