# How to create resideMenu on Android?

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu

I want to create an application with resideMenu like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/master/Demo.gif?2). How to do it? Or is there any useful library that can help to realize it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Its simple use translate animation in sequence with scale animation.

Comment: Thanks, but have you got an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465774/android-how-to-make-slide-menu-like-facebook-spotify-and-google/15879886#15879886 well you can use **Scale Animation** in sequence with **Translate Animation**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this library :
Android Reside Menu on github

https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

Comment: And if you want your own custom view for menu:
public class CustomResideMenuItem extends ResideMenuItem {
    public CustomResideMenuItem_logo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_residemenu_image, this);
    }
}