# SplitView on iPhone using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, tableview

I just found some codes with splitview on iPhone, but all of these codes are using xib files. I want a demo using storyboard. The splitview that I mean is that one like facebook uses: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqJW5.png

If anybody know some source that I can use for my study, I really appreciate that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What the Facebook app uses is a highly customized view controller.  There is no true UISplitViewController available for iPhone.  If you want something like what Facebook did, you will have to write it from scratch (or nearly so).

Comment: That's true, there's no UISplitViewController available on iPhone. But I found some customize ViewControllers that do the same thing that facebook do. If you want to check this out, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-but-on-iphone.

I just don't found these codes on storyboard, just on xbi files. :(

Comment: I don't even see any xibs in the first answer on that question.  Did I miss them?

Comment: The xib files are in this project: https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo, sorry for the mess.  What I wanted to say, was that I already found a split view based application on iPhone using xib files, now I'm looking for any app using storyboard, just for study the class.