# IOS facebook app slide option menu

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

I need a control that will split a screen into 2 different views when click.
It is kind of like this  [1]: http://i51.tinypic.com/2112zwh.png
I had used inferis/view deck but it screw out my navigation controller.
Basically it can't perform any segue
I am using StoryBoard with navigation controller and also tab controller.

Anyone has any idea how to have this kind of menu but works with storyboard and navigation controller, tab controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the [JTRevealSidebar](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) Project to build mine. I used storyboards, and segues in my project and got everything working without any troubles. Take a look at the demos, and it should be pretty easy to implement. If you have any specific issues when you do get it implemented feel free to post questions about your issues.

Comment: Can you share how you implemented this with storyboards ?

Answer (score 12):

I made a video (3 parts) on youtube on how to make a sliding menu like the on you are looking for. I show you how to set up the project and get everything linked up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

You will have to create UINavigationControllers instead of plain UIView controllers if you want to use that tutorial, but its basically just selecting one or the other.

The cool thing about ECSlidingViewController (Its the one I use) is that just about everything you want to configure (how far a view slides, the animations, left or right side) is done with a single line of code (sometimes 2 or 3 lines)

Try it out and see if it works for you?

Comment: hey Kyle. thanks for the vid. one question tho, i don't understand how the button tap toggles the menu when all we do on button tap is anchor the top view to the edge. i implemented the same flow in my app and the button doesn't toggle the menu back. why does it work in your sample when resetTopViewController is never invoked on a button click. hmmmmm.

Comment: Kyle, haven't check out your code yet, but I skipped through your tutorials. Can the menu be made to slide in from the right? Meaning the menu slides in from the right, on top of the current viewcontroller, instead of the viewcontroller sliding out to reveal the menu.

Comment: @Kyle anyway you can provide the source project again having some issues and would like to look at it for reference if possible and the link to the dropbox does not work. Thanks!