# Making a segue within a navigation controller without pushing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm making an app where you at one part should be able to switch back and forth between three pages and pick files from each one of them. These will be added to an array as you pick them.

Problem is that the only way I know to link between these pages would be to use a tab bar, which doesn't work within a navigation controller...

Do you have any idea of what might work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the exact answer to the question, but can very well be a solution to other people finding this thread...

After a while of experimenting, I found out that I could just change the content in the UITableView for each button push instead of having three separate UITableView's.

Answer (score 0):

What about a UIScrollView`?

Make your three pages as separate `UIView`'s in your xib. Then, add them side by side into your scroll view in `viewDidLoad`.

If you set `paging = YES` on your scroll view then that should work.

Comment: Hmm... Is it possible to make buttons for a certain page then? Because i would need some form of labeling. Also all of the pages are dynamic UITableViews. You can't add those to a UIScrollView right?

Comment: You can add a `UITableView` to a `UIScrollView` just fine as long as you only scroll horizontally in the scroll view (and don't try to do crazy things like zoom!) And your three `UIView`s can contain anything you want - `UIbutton`s etc - they're just normal `UIView`s!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you well, but what do you think about using a UISplitViewController?

Using its MasterViewController as a place with buttons to switch between the three pages and in the DetailViewController the corresponding View of each one.

Comment: Without knowing what it is, it sounds like what I could need. Would it make a number parallel pages to switch between without having to push? Am I right?

Comment: Uhm.. you could have an entire (and different) navigation flow on each one of the three pages you're talking about. This is an example of what I'm talking about. Is a split view like the one at "Settings", http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/split_view.png

Comment: Ahh... No but as the tag says it's in iPhone. Thing is I have 3 table views that should be okay to go back and forth between without pushing over and over on each other. Get what I mean?

Comment: Uhm i've done something similar for iPad, for the phone maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-but-on-iphone