# What is this button called?

Tags: ios, facebook, button, navigation

This might be a very quick question to which I can't seem to find the answer to:

What is the button type called which we see on the facebook's navigation bar on the left hand side?

[image]

Any special name for it?

I checked out the standard buttons on apple's human interface, but can't seem to find it listed:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html

Comment: It does not have a particular name.  The icon inn question is used by several apps for different purposes too.  I'd check for any Facebook manuals on the app and see what they call it.

Comment: If you're after re-creating the function of that button, there's several open source frameworks for it out there, http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mfsidemenu is one example. That site has a ton more different implementations of that control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this button popping up in a number of apps lately. You might call it the Splitview reveal button, or the Sidebar Reveal Button. I don't believe there is an official name for it, but there are a number of open source projects that are implementing it.

Here is a stackoverflow link covering how to program one:

[SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-but-on-iphone)

Comment: Cool thank you! Yes, I was able to implement the slide view / sidebar reveal thing - was just curious what the button was called as lately a LOT of apps are using it. Your answers seems so confirm there is no special name for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The button doesn't have a special name from the point of view of Cocoa or Apple Development. The icon can be used to show a list or menu item or anything else depending upon the development practice or UI guidelines of different applications. It would be better to check if facebook documentation has any special name for it.