# How it call the new navigation design iOS

Tags: ios, templates

I am looking for a template or feature of the design like in facebook.
the navigation if you swipe left you can choose another menu point.
If you have a name or something else I dont know how can i looking in the internet.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone

Comment: @creativ you can share the [direct answer like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777624/468724)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two quick links by searching goole with string **`facebook menu item project iphone`**

1. [JTRevealSidebar for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtrevealsidebar)
2. [Facebook side-menu easy to use component](http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/338/Facebook+side-menu+easy+to+use+component/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Inferis](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) library. It allows you to setup left, right, top and bottom controllers.