# multiple layered split view like sparrow app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, uisplitviewcontroller

a question similar to this was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone) before and there are [tonnes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777624/766570) of open source examples for a single layered split view.. but I was wondering if there was one similar to the sparrow email client app, where you can drag/hide multiple views..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [this](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) and [this](https://github.com/pyro2927/JPStackedViewController)

Both contains functionality which you are looking for and available on [github](https://github.com/).

Comment: [JPStackedViewController](https://github.com/pyro2927/JPStackedViewController) is more like the one I was looking for.. although you can't drag the body of the UINavBar, just the bar itself.. the [other](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) link is the same as the ones in my question..

Comment: just to clarify.. [JPStackedViewController](https://github.com/pyro2927/JPStackedViewController) works if you drag the body as well if you set the flag `https://github.com/pyro2927/JPStackedViewController`.. so my previous point was wrong

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.cocoacontrols.com.
There are plenty of out-of-the box ready implementations for this kind of cunktionality.

Searches:

for "Stack": [1](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stack)

for "Panel": [2](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=panel)

for "Slide": [3](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slide)

for "Side": [4](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=side)

Comment: i'm afraid none of those actually fit the bill