# How this iphone uiview behavior name

Tags: iphone, uiview, behavior

How can I make this `UIView` behavior?

[image: Step one – touch any setting button]
[image: step tow – current window go to the left or right]

I see this in several apps and it's interesting – is this standard or custom?

Comment: romaji... create UIView and add it on this button touch method for display

Comment: Here is the list of open source custom controls like you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a third party plugin for sliding menu: https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Or you could implement this tween by yourself with

```
CGRect frame = yourView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
[UIVIew animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^(void){
    frame.origin.x += 100; //<-Here's the animation
    yourView.frame = frame;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below link and download the Source code :)

[Check Link](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jasidepanels)

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom control. It's not a standard control of iOS. Here, is the [example](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu) to start with.