# Slide back in UINavigationController like in Facebook for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I saw the Facebook app update for iOS (6.1.1) and it has a rely nice slide back function. For now I have a `UISlideGestureRecognizer` that when is called a do a `[self.navigationController popViewController:YES];`. But how can I make it with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` like in the Facebook app? Should I build my own `UINavigationController`?

I do not know more than this (yet):

```
backView1 = [[self.navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navCon.viewControllers.count - 2] view];
backView2 = [[self.navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navCon.viewControllers.count - 1] view];
```

Please help in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: First of all I never heard of `UISlideGestureRecognizer ` :)). Second check this project https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Comment: I mean UISwipeGestureRecongnizer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a subclass of UINavigationController to do that. Here you go: https://github.com/MarcoSero/MSSlideNavigationController

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about slide out menu you can partially 'swipe', see this for several examples.

[SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

Comment: No, I'm more talking about: when you are in the newsfeed and then touch a story (The Facebook app shows that story with some code lik: [self, navigationController pushViewController:con];) then when you want to go back you can now slide your finger from left to right to go back to the news feed. Understand?

Answer (score 0):

To add effect of Slide back in UINavigationController add the following code line and add gesture recognizer delegate

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```