# Sliding ViewController animation like the Facebook Iphone app

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I was wondering if anybody has an idea on how to do the sliding segue/animation that the Facebook Iphone app uses to reveal it's menu. I like that the entire NavigationController can slide over to reveal the menu but I can't find any tutorials that explain how this is set up.  Any body have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you could have just searched once on google you could have got the result. Here is the list http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777624/468724

Comment: I did search on google but the link you posted describes it differently.

Comment: The reference given by Inder Kumar Rathore, is the correct one. For future reference, search CocoaControls.com and GitHub first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing as you and came to the conclusion of using this [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

Its a great and easy class to use and the developer implements several examples fro you to look at or derive your project from... Its great !!! :)

If you have any questions of how to use it.. dont hesitate to send me or John Lluch (the developer) a message on how to use it.

Comment: That's just what I'm looking for. Thanks!!!

Comment: :) as said, If you have any questions about how to use it... post some other questions, send me an email, or John... We're both named John, cept I perfer Johnny haha

Comment: @jsetting32, i add SWRevealController to my app, my app is universal. But i have about 10 viewcontrollre are there. how to add those 10 viewcontrollers in menu? any idea?

Comment: Check out the `RearViewController` class `SWRevealController` supplies you and import your viewcontrollers in `RearViewController.h` - e.g `MyViewController.h`. Now to add your controllers to the view you need to look at 3 methods. First check out `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and add how ever many rows "viewControllers" you'd like to add to the tableview, then check out  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you specify the name of the cell and `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which you would specify which viewController would be loaded when a respective row number is selected.

Comment: If you need more help just post a question and I'll make a fully fledged answer. It really is all about understanding `UITableView`s though. Maybe go through a youtube tutorial on `UITableViewController`s or check out the Apple Docs - which are not horribly documented but dense in material.