# Partial Slide Out Action in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I'm trying to figure out the best way to replicate the action that the Rise Alarm Clock ([video of action](http://youtu.be/MgGaY6V0ajo?t=28s)) has.

I've been attempting to duplicate it using slide out navigation tutorials, however it's not quite the same and I'm struggling. Any tutorials or ideas on the easiest implementation of it? I don't know if I need a subview, or just to move the main view on the drag, and move in another view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ECSlidingViewController, it performs a similar sliding effect. 
https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

You can adjust the 'peak' amount in the MenuViewController.m in viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:255.0f];
```