# How to Push a ViewController from Left Over another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

I want to make a Navigation Drawer Like This:
[image]

I saw many third party libararies. But I want to do it from my own.

Here is what I am trying :

```
   __block UIViewController *sourceViewController = self;

NavigationDrawerVC *controller = [[NavigationDrawerVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationDrawerVC" bundle:nil];


__block UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)controller;

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                            forKey:kCATransition];


[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
```

But I am getiing o/p like this:

[image]

When I click on Button My Screen Changes Like this:

[image]

My Previous VIewController also moving.

I want to make it Fix. And also I am not able to stop it at certain point.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663692/android-like-navigation-drawer-for-ios?

Comment: @Newyork167 I tried that...PAN gesture is not detecting in that

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a child controller for this.

Here's a very simplified code which demonstrates this concept. It adds a child view controller and animates it to the middle of the screen. This should at least give you a starting point:

```
UIViewController *drawerVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
drawerVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self addChildViewController:drawerVC];
drawerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:drawerVC.view];
[drawerVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    drawerVC.view.frame = CGRectOffset(drawerVC.view.frame, drawerVC.view.frame.size.width * 0.5, 0);
}];
```

Comment: I have added it...But how Can I add pan gesture to it

Comment: @RahulMishra you asked how to push a drawer-like view-controller. If you're struggling with the pan gesture I suggest that you ask a separate question and provide additional info about what's not working and what have you tried, or at least update this one.