# like menu shown in image with iOS 6,7 compatible

Tags: ios, menu, slide

I need an sliding menu mentioned in the pic which is compatible for iOS 6 and iOS 7

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path). It will show you how to do this on both side of the phone.

If you don't want to read all of this :

The main idea is to have a view below the main view. When you slide or touch your menu button, you just move your top view by doing the following (i did this on a class inherited by all of my view controllers, but you're free to do it anywhere you want / need it) :

```
// self.isMenuOpened is a flag to save menu state and set the move distance (and a few other things)

// Init move distance
float move = 270; // 270 is arbitrary value, you can set it as you like
if (self.isMenuOpened) { move = -move; }

// Moves all view except menu
[UIView beginAnimations:@"openMenu" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDurationShort];

// Navigation bar frame moving (if you have one)
CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(navFrame.origin.x + move,
                                                           navFrame.origin.y,
                                                           navFrame.size.width,
                                                           navFrame.size.height);

// Call switching move on each view
BOOL first = true;
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {

    if (first) { first = false; } // First view is menu if it's on minimum zIndex
    else {
        CGRect mainViewFrame = view.frame;
        [view setUserInteractionEnabled:self.isMenuOpened]; // Disable your main view as it still visible
        view.frame = CGRectMake(mainViewFrame.origin.x + move, mainViewFrame.origin.y,
                                mainViewFrame.size.width, mainViewFrame.size.height);

    }
}


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I iterate through all of my subviews because, in a few cases, i added a view or two. But if you have a single view (and then your menu below), you don't have to do all the iteration stuff. Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome and simple library

https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu

which supports left and right menus and fully customizable