# UISplitViewController - side-by-side or overlay in portrait orientation

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to implement the type of functionality as seen in the image below. I do not know if this is a `UISplitViewController` that has its trait collection overridden to display side-by-side in portrait orientation or if this is two `UITableViewController`s using a custom animation object. Is it possible to achieve this with a `UISplitViewController` or is this simply using an animation object? Side-by-side or the primary (master) view controller overlaying the secondary (detail) view controller is something I am also interested in.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [SplitView like Facebook app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

I'm using `SWRevealViewController` and it's great.

[Github](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController),
[Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/tag/swrevealviewcontroller/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a third-party library?

Comment: Only by implementing it yourself, I suppose. `SWRevealViewController`, and the myriad alternatives out there, are free to use in commercial projects. I'd thoroughly recommend using a third-party library as there are no legal worries. Also, if you want, you can read the source code and see how they've done it, and get ideas on how you might do it yourself.